# Search Display to not show results until search bar is tapped

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I think I may be missing something obvious:

Is there a simple way to modify the UISearchBar or UISearchDisplayController so that it doesn't reload the view after each letter typed but only after the Search button is hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Most of the examples I found search the text here:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

but I just didn't implement that method and instead just wrote my own search function which I called here:

```
// called when keyboard search button pressed

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    [self fetchTheSearchString:searchBar.text];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```